# Accessing the Computer Configuration node in Group Policy settings

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am trying to configure Terminal Services printing related group policy settings and the technet doc says I need to go here:

**Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Printer Redirection**

I open up `Server Manager`, expand `Features`, `Group Policy Management`, expand the forest, domain and my domain but after that I cannot seem to find the `Computer Configuration` node the article refers to.

This is a link to the document I am referring to:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519193(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each GPO has its own "Computer Configuration" setting.  You'd need to right-click the GPO that is responsible for applying the settings in question, and click "Edit..." to edit that GPO.  From the new console window that launches, you should see that the GPO has a Computer Configuration node and a User Configuration Node.

Answer (score 3):

Run gpedit.msc, there you have "Computer configuration" node and "Administrative templates" subnode.

Comment: This will only open *local* group policy management. The OP appears to be asking about *domain* policy.

Comment: @tfrederick74656 Would you share some difference between domain and local?